# how set middleware gorillas/csrf in framework gin from Go

Tags: go, frameworks, csrf

learning gin, framework for go, i need insert a csrf token, searchin i find the gorillas utils for make csrf and other thing, but my problem is the next.
this

```golang
csrfMiddleware := csrf.Protect([]byte("32-byte-long-auth-key"))
```

make this type

```golang
func Protect(authKey []byte, opts ...Option) func(http.Handler) http.Handler
```

and try use this middleware function whith gin, especifically:

```golang
g := gin.Default()
g.Use(csrfMiddleware)  ///set a middleware
```

how can use middlware csrf Protect with gin??, in the doc claims to be compatible.
i confussed.

with this code yes working, but I don't know if it's correct, in the doc says if middleware works correctly, csrf.Token should generate a token, else, generate nothing

```golang
type helloWorldHandler struct{}

func (h helloWorldHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("entro")
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    csrfMiddleware := csrf.Protect([]byte("32-byte-long-auth-key"))

    var d helloWorldHandler
    r.Use(gin.WrapH(csrfMiddleware(d)))


    r.GET("/test/session/:id", func(c *gin.Context) {

        a := csrf.Token(c.Request)

        fmt.Println(a)
        c.Header("X-CSRF-Token", csrf.Token(c.Request))

    })

    // Listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: @Ignaio you can check if generated csrf token is getting added to headers in response or not to make sure its working

Comment: yes, was added, and can recieve in request, now do not understan how function the cookies,